# listview shows only one value in one block

Tags: android, database, listview

i have a listview and its data values is separated by blocks( Item1, Item2...) but i want to know how to show (Item 1, Sub Item 1...) ?
well here is the code that shows only the Item, so how do i show the Item and the Sub Item?

code:

```
           //LISTVIEW database CONTATO
    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome" + " ASC ");
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the code i putted there but still gives me errors and i dont see where it gets the values from yet.

```
             //LISTVIEW database CONTATO
    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> listItem;

    Cursor c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome" + " ASC ");
    c.moveToFirst();

    listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    listItem.put("nome", "your_item_text");
    listItem.put("telefone", "your_subitem_text");
    items.add(listItem);

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.custom_list_layout, new String[]{"item", "subitem"}, new int[]{R.id.text_item, R.id.text_subitem});

    user.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Are you really asking about a ListView? Your code shows a Spinner, not a ListView. You might wanna be clearer about that.

Comment: oh '-' sorry i will edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleAdapter`, not the `ArrayAdapter` to populate the `ListView`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html
There you will have an *array* of fields to populate for each item, like:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> listItem;

listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
listItem.put("item", "your_item_text");
listItem.put("subitem", "your_subitem_text");
items.add(listItem);

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.custom_list_layout, new String[]{"item", "subitem"}, new int[]{R.id.text_item, R.id.text_subitem});

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Remember also to create `custom_list_layout.xml` for your ListView items, and make sure it contains textViews with proper ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_item"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_subitem"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but this is a bit advanced and i dont know much so i get confused but i know there is already the item and sub item in the listview just want to know how to make the "telefone" show in the listview aswell as the name

Comment: ok, but it is textviews, i need listview because when i add a contact in the database i want to show Item as Name and Sub Item as Phone

Comment: custom_list_layout.xml is responsible for each item. The code above describes a listview, in which _every item_ consists of two textviews.

Comment: have you created custom_list_layout.xml in /res/layout/ ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16713/discussion-between-vasily-sochinsky-and-alexandre-f)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), that is exactly for this user case.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own custom adapter extending either the ArrayAdapter or the BaseAdapter and you will also have to create an xml layout for your items in the list. 
If you are new to ListView go through this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) on ListView.